# Collapse flex items

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions

I am trying to animate a few flex items which should collapse just beside one another when they are scaled down. 
For example: see [this pen](https://codepen.io/0xfa1l/pen/PBgmxX).

```css
.flex-cont {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: scale(0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-cont'>
  <div class='flex-item'>
    Test
  </div>
  <div class='flex-item'>
    Test
  </div>
  <div class='flex-item'>
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the items have a gap between them. I want them to be just beside each other. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's how `transform: scale()` is intended to work. You will need to change the width instead.

Comment: Setting a width doesn't help. The gap is still there.

Comment: You can use `position` or `transform: translate` to reposition the elements when they are scaled down?

Comment: :( Doesn't work.

Comment: what is the intended result?

Comment: The items should not have any white-space between them.

Comment: I can't fully understand your question, but I noticed you have a 10px margin between them. Your transformation has to set it to 0.

Comment: You can't do this with a *transform* as it's **purely visual** the element doesn't actually get smaller....it's just *drawn smaller*.

Comment: @abhisek are you looking for this - https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/u8gj6tms/

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is make your margin negative on `.flex-item`. From your example, setting it to...

```
  .flex-item {
      margin: 0 -13px;
      background: red;
      padding: 10px;
      transform: scale(0.25);
   }
```

did the trick.

**EDIT**

If you want to maintain the position of leftmost item then...

```
.flex-item {
    margin:0 -46px 0px 10px;
    background:red;
    padding:10px;
    transform:scale(0.25);
}
```

Comment: hmmm 2 downvotes, no one explains why. Does exactly what op asked for. Gotta love this site sometimes...